# $http.get request gets cancelled

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get data from a server in my Ionic app, using $http.get. But when I execute the request, it seems to get cancelled by something.

```
$scope.login = function() {



       var canceller = $q.defer();

        var requestPromise = $http.get("http://Myurl/users");

        requestPromise.
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password).success(function(data) {

                $state.go('home');
            }).error(function(data) {
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Login failed!',
                    template: 'Please check your credentials!'
                });
            });

            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if(data.status === 0) {
                    // Request cancelled
                }
                else {
                    // Other error
                    throw 'Error ' + status
                }
            });
           canceller.resolve();


        }
```

Service.Js

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.service('LoginService', function($q) {
    return {
        loginUser: function(name, pw) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promise = deferred.promise;

            if (name == 'user' && pw == 'secret') {
                deferred.resolve('Welcome ' + name + '!');
            } else {
                deferred.reject('Wrong credentials.');
            }
            promise.success = function(fn) {
                promise.then(fn);
                return promise;
            }
            promise.error = function(fn) {
                promise.then(null, fn);
                return promise;
            }
            return promise;
        }
    }
})
```

about error in my console just tell me request canceled there is  no syntax error

Comment: open the developer tools and see what error you are getting ?

Comment: when i try to call just http.get without user.login dat return success and data  but when i try to call LoginService.loginUser in side success that return error

Comment: What error message do you get? and can you post your LoginService code here

Comment: just tell me request cancled